# how to get the selected date from calender control to my textbox

Tags: asp.net

I have a calendar control with two textboxes. One textbox is for fromdate and other is for todate.

I need to select two dates. How can I get the dates selected from the calender control into my textboxes?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your calendar control returns the data, but you basically just assign the returned value to the textbox value property:

```
document.getElementById('textbox1').value = calendarControl.getDate();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use calender extender.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt_InvoiceDate" runat="server" CssClass="txtborder" Width="70px"
ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton3" runat="server" ImageUrl="images/ico_calendar.gif" />
<asp:CalendarExtender ID="txt_date_of_visit_CalendarExtender" runat="server" Enabled="True"
Format="dd-MM-yyyy" TargetControlID="txt_InvoiceDate" PopupButtonID="ImageButton3">
</asp:CalendarExtender>
```